# Creating Function that creates specific output using {} in output

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have 2 lists:
`members = ['Alex', 'Danny', 'Kieran', 'Zoe', 'Caroline']`
`visitors = ['Scott', 'Helen', 'Raj', 'Danny']`

I'm trying to create a function that returns a string in the format `Member present: {person}.`where `{person}` is replaced by the first name in the visitors to be identified as a member.

But i'm struggling to implement the `{}` within the return.

Any ideas on how to move forward with this?

Thanks

Comment: Add the function that you have written so far and read [mcve].

Comment: Please add sample output and the code you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `format` string method or (since Python 3.6) f-strings.

```
"Member present: {person}".format(person)
```

uses the former,

```
f"Member present: {person}"
```

is how to write it with the latter. So overall you could write:

```
for person in visitors:
    if person in members:
        print(f"Member present: {person}")
        break
else:
    print("No members visited")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the two lists to get the member that exists in both, and then wrap it in a function

```
members = ['Alex', 'Danny', 'Kieran', 'Zoe', 'Caroline'] 
visitors = ['Scott', 'Helen', 'Raj', 'Danny']

def member_name(members, visitors):
    return [x for x in members if x in visitors]

result = member_name(members, visitors)

for member in result:
    print("Member present: {}".format({member}))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Member present: {'Danny'}
```